# using 3 classes to implement a program error

Tags: class, printf, public, java

What I am trying to accomplish here is launching a program using three separate classes and I seem to get errors. I am relatively new to this and not entirely comprehend the java language yet. So please go easy on me and feel free to give me additional advice on anything that may be conducive to hone my skill.

```
package com.weightroom;

public class Baeyul { //박스 생성
    
    String name,gender;
    int [] threemax = new int [3];
    int weight,total,rank;

}
```

*The second class*

```
package com.weightroom;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Record {

    int inwon;
    
    Baeyul[] bae;
    
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public void set() {
        
        do {
            System.out.print("인원 수? ");
            inwon= sc.nextInt();
        }while(inwon<1||inwon>5);
        
        bae= new Baeyul[inwon];
    
    }
    
    public void input() {
        
        String[] title = {"벤치?","데드?","스쿼트"};
        
        //반복문
        
        for(int i=0;i<inwon;i++) {
            
            bae[i] = new Baeyul();
            
            System.out.print((i+1)+ "번째 이름? ");
            bae[i].name = sc.next();
        
            System.out.print("성별? ");
            bae[i].gender = sc.next();
            
            System.out.print("몸무게? ");
            bae[i].weight = sc.nextInt();
            
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++) { //벤데스?
                
                System.out.print(title[j]);
                bae[i].threemax[j] = sc.nextInt();
                bae[i].total+= bae[i].threemax[j];
            }
            
        }       
    }
        
        private void ranking() {
            
            int i,j;
            
            for (i=0;i<inwon;i++) {
                bae[i].rank=1;
        }
            
        for(i=0;i<inwon-1;i++) {
            for(j=1;j<inwon;j++) {
                
                if(bae[i].total>bae[j].total) {
                    bae[j].rank++;
                }else if(bae[i].total<bae[j].total) {
                    bae[i].rank++;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
        
        public void print() {
            
            ranking(); 
            
            for(int i=0;i<inwon;i++) {
                System.out.printf("%6s", bae[i].name);
                System.out.printf("%4s", bae[i].gender);
                System.out.printf("%4d", bae[i].weight);
                
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
                    System.out.printf("%4d",bae[i].threemax);
                }
                
                System.out.printf("%4d",bae[i].total);
                System.out.printf("%4d|n",bae[i].rank);
                
        }
    }
}
```

*The third class

```
package com.weightroom;

public class RecordUse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Record li= new Record();
        
        li.set();
        li.input();
        li.print();

    }

}
```

- 

```
launch
     jamesException in thread "main"    1 100java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [I
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
        at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
        at com.weightroom.Record.print(Record.java:83)
        at com.weightroom.RecordUse.main(RecordUse.java:11)
```

Comment: your question makes it seem as if your goal is to implement an error, it's a bit weird that way. What exactly is the line that throws the error? Check that one, and add a breakpoint to it, to see if the variable is what you expect it to be

Answer (score 0):

In the print method you haven't put the index of the threemax array, So when you try to print the array in a %4d format, it throws an exception.

Change threemax as threemax [ j ].

**Like below**

Use

```
 for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
      System.out.printf("%4d",bae[i].threemax[j]);
 }
```

Instead of

```
for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
      System.out.printf("%4d",bae[i].threemax);
}
```

in the print method.

Comment: Thank you so much dude. The program runs fine now!!